# ASP.NET MVC : render a string in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this code part from a view

```
<td>
  @if (item.ProductsRequest != null)
  {
      Html.TextBox("yes");
  }
  else
  {
      Html.TextBox("no");
  }
</td>
```

But when I render it the string "yes" or "no" don't show up in the browser.

I want to write "yes" in the column if there is some information on the `item.ProductsRequest`.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to write the value out, then simply put the string in the respective if-else block via a `<text>` block:

```
<td>
  @if (item.ProductsRequest != null)
  {
      <text>yes</text>
  }
  else
  {
      <text>no<text>
</td>
```

If you really want to be succinct:

```
<td>
    @(item?.ProductsRequest != null ? "yes" : "no")
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

as Rion Williams just said, you can use this code below to accomplish your goal:

```
<td>
  @if (item.ProductsRequest != null)
  {
      <text>yes</text>
  }
  else
  {
      <text>no<text>
</td>
```

But if you want to render using the TextBox function, you can do it this way:

```
  @if (item.ProductsRequest != null)
  {
      @Html.TextBox("myTextBox", "yes")
  }
  else
  {
      @Html.TextBox("myTextBox", "no")  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write "yes" in the column

You don't need to use `@Html.TextBox`, just display text in this way

```
<td>
  @if (item.ProductsRequest != null)
  {
      <span>yes</span>;
  }
  else
  {
      <span>no</span>;
  }
</td>
```